# Making a reusable predicate for EntitySet<T>, IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

In my LINQ to SQL setup I have various tables which are mapped to classes which basically support the same interface to support versioning, i.e.

```
public interface IValid
{
    int? validTo { get; }
    int validFrom { get; }
}
```

The LINQ to SQL classes derive from this interface like this:

```
public partial class representationRevision : IValid
{
}
```

Now I would like to define a DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) way of filtering `EntitySet<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` so that the resulting lists are valid for a specific revision. I've tried doing this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{

    public static IQueryable<T> ValidFor<T>(this IQueryable<T> v, int? revision)
        where T : IValid
    {
        return v.Where(cr => ((cr.validFrom <= revision) &&
            ((cr.validTo == null) || (cr.validTo > revision)))
            || ((revision == null) && (cr.validTo == null))
            );
    }
}
```

But this gives problems on `EntitySet<T>`. I added a special implementation for EntitySet which first calls AsQueryable(), but this throws an exception. Undeterred I tried making a predicate so I could use the `Where(predicate)` approach:

```
    public static Expression<Func<contentRevision, bool>> IsValidFor(int? revision)
    {
        return ((cr) => ((cr.validFrom <= revision) &&
            ((cr.validTo == null) || (cr.validTo > revision)))
            || ((revision == null) && (cr.validTo == null)));
    }
```

When used with `.Where<contentRevision>(IsValidFor(revision))` it gives errors like:

> Error  5   'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet' does 
>       not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload
>       'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where
>       (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' has 
>       some invalid arguments

Note that this is even without using the IValid interface... I've been trying all kinds of variations on this theme (like adding the int parameter) but they all invariably seem to fail. Any pointers to get me in the right direction?

Comment: In your static expression function above, the first type parameter is `contentRevision`, is that a typo?  I would expect it to be `IValid`.  Also the error you show at the bottom appears to be a result of passing in a predicate with 3 type parameters.  What happens if you pass in the predicate as shown (`Expression<Func<IValid, bool>>`)?  I've used this a lot and it works fine, I can't figure out from your post why your code won't compile.

Comment: It's in the comment below the code "Note that this is even without using the IValid interface". Basically I tried to get it to work without using IValid first, but at the moment there is no difference in behaviour. I think it's something specifically to do with EntitySet<T>: if I rewrite my code to do table joins everything seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about `EntitySet<T>` so will focus on `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`.

To allow the LINQ provider to evaluate the expression trees that `IQueryable<T>` uses for its expression arguments one needs to ensure the underlying interface is preserved. Otherwise do everything in term of `IEnumerable<T>` (i.e. if you are OK to pull the whole dataset into local memory and then process it there, rather than in the database, just use LINQ to Objects).

The other option is the `AsQueryable` extension method (part of `Queryable` class) which converts a `IEnumerable<T>` to a `IQueryable<T>`, and then you can share the rest of the code.

```
IQueryable<T> SomeSharedQuery(this IQueryable<T> source) {
    return source.(LINQ query operators...);
}
IQueryable<T> SomeSharedQuery(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
    return source.AsQueryable().SomeSharedQuery();
}
```

So you have the shared code, with an adapter method.

Comment: That works brilliantly, but not for EntitySet<T> though. The AsQueryable() does not have a translation to SQL (oddly enough).

Comment: @Matthijs: Bawed on the docs `EntitySet<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so you will get a match. Given `EntitySet<T>` is about lazy loading of parts of an existing query you don't gain anything from an `IQueryable<T>` implementation on it... if you want the db to do the work across the association include that in the original query.